The initial SELECT runs fine, but adding a LEFT JOIN causes an error
I am a user of PolarDB for Xscale. When I executed the statement, the first part of the Select ran without issues, but adding a left join in the second part resulted in the error shown in the image. How should I resolve this?
error image
This is my first time using the PolarDB database, and I couldn't find the error code in the documentation.

Your picture does not show your complete query. It'd also be better if you could paste the query. Beyond that I can read "java.lang.NullPointerException". I know nothing about PolarDB, but that does not sound like the kind of error that's expected (ie, this is not something you expect to get in Java)
